# Pages refresh automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys im still learning.

How to make pages automatically refresh after its direct to index pages.

is this the correct code?

```
  if(data.success === 0) {
                alertError(data.message);
                
            }else{
              
                localStorage['success'] = "Document has been approved successfully.";
               
                window.location.href = "index.php";
              window.location.reload();
            }
```

Comment: Once you redirect everything in current page including script is gone and new page knows nothing about it. Rather than simply asking if the code is correct, proper thing to do is to tell us what is expected and what it isn't doing to meet those expectations

Comment: A page can either be redirected or refreshed but cannot do both. So your code in incorrect because the last line (reload) will never be reached or executed. If you ARE on index page, just remove the locaion.href line and page will refresh.